# Searchbar filter based on json

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm having a name value to my tableviewcell like so..

```
for asd in orderDetails {

    if let jsonStr = asd.value(forKey: "customerJson") as? String {

        let data = jsonStr?.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!

        do {
            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [String: Any] {
                for item in json {
                    if item.key == "first_Name" {
                        cell.nameLabel.text = item.value as? String //ASSIGNED HERE
                    }

                }
            }

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to search on the search bar based on this name. While searching in other cases where the core data attributes were mentioned directly I did something like so which worked fine..

```
    filtered = self.newProdDetails.filter({( data : NewProduct) -> Bool in
        return (data.name?.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))! //Here the entity NewProduct has an attribute name
    })
```

But in the current scenario, the attribute is a json string called `customer_json` given like so and I wanted to filter based on the `first_name`..

```
customer_json={
  "mobile_number”:”9876543210”,
  "first_name”:”testName”,
  "last_name”:”testLastName”,
  "seller_id":"93"
}
```

Comment: What are the contents that you are saving in newProdDetails? Also show the details of NewProduct, ideally you should be able to filter with properties NewProduct

Comment: .@anoop4real `newProdDetails ` will not come in this scenario. That was just an example I gave to show how filtering was done in other places. In my scenario I have `orderDetails `. In case of `newProdDetails` the attribute was `name` and in this scenario the attribute is `customer_json ` and I have to filter based on the `first_name ` within the `customer_json`.

Comment: Ok, what is inside orderDeatils? Object ? dictionary? I assume that you are getting an OrderDetails JSON data from webservice and in that you have customer info right? Why dont you make an OrderDetails object and customer be a property of that which is another object, parse in one shot... look at www.json4swift.com, it will generate objects from JSON and then work and modify it. Also can you post your full JSON. Hope I understood you correctly

Comment: `orderDetails ` has many attributes. Some of them are straight-forward ones like selling price etc. While some other attributes are dictionaries or array of dictionaries. And one of them is `customer_json `. In my case I want to filter based on `first_Name` and it is not depended on the other attributes of `orderDetails`

Answer (score 2):

simply parse your JSON into the array or dictionary a/c to json with help :

```
let arrayJson =  JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:....
```

.....

then apply Search simply on an array like this  :

```
 let filterArr = arrayJson.filter {
        return (($0["first_name"] as! String).lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))
    }
```

Comment: I tried as you suggested @Pradeep Kashyap like so ` let filterArr = json.filter {
                                return (($0["first_name"] as! String).lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))
                            }` But it gives the error `Value of tuple type '(key: String, value: Any)' has no member 'subscript'`

Comment: yes u will this error bcz this answer will on array and i think you are using Tuple Array if u are using tuple array then simply use something like this ...($0.value)

Comment: if its not working then post your array here with type then i can give the exact answer ...

Comment: There is an issue @Pradeep Kashyap. `filterArr` should confirm to the coredata type which in this case is `Order`  and `filterArr ` is of type `[String: Any]`. So how do we handle that...?

Comment: filter closure will return the same array as like your main array(on which you apply filter ) so that error should not occur. or define filter array type Order then try....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165465/discussion-between-v-bw-and-pradeep-kashyap).